# Get to-many relationship property of Managed Object as Array of Managed Objects (not NSOrderedSet)

Tags: xcode, core-data, swift4

I have a `Collection` and a `Member` Managed Object in Core Data.
`Collection` has a to-many relationship `members`, that can contain `Member` objects. `Member` objects should be uniquely associated to a single `Collection`.

I want to be able to use the objects in this relationship as Managed Objects for use in populating my Table View Controller, like so:

`let members : [Member] = someCollection.members`

However, the `members` property seems to be an `NSOrderedSet?` object, and not an array of `Member`.

To this extent, I have tried the following (found on the internet, as I'm very new to Swift) and I am also trying to catch the situation where the relationship field could be `nil`. It doesn't work for me, and I don't understand why.

```
let members = someCollection.members?.array as! [Member]

if members != nil {
//Do something with the array

else {
//handle the case that there is no entry in the relationship field
}
```

I am getting the following error:

`Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong, and if possible, provide a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `array` returns a non-optional you have to optional bind `members`. If the check succeeds you can safely force unwrap the array. The code checks also if the array is not empty.

```
if let members = someCollection.members, members.count > 0 {
   let memberArray = members.array as! [Member]
   //Do something with the array
else {
   //handle the case that there is no entry in the relationship field
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but I get `Value of type 'NSOrderedSet' has no member 'isEmpty'`